# Composition of void method used in void method? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, matrix, void

I started learning Java about 2 weeks ago, so please, don't be judgy. 
I'm doing this program with a two-dimensional array (a picture), which I want to rotate on 90 degrees (already done, tested, it works) and 180. My methods are void and I want to use the 90 degrees one twice (composed?) in the 180 degrees one, but it doesn't work.

This is my 90 method:

```
public void rotate90(){
        for (int r = 0; r < w; r++) {
             for (int c = 0; c < h; c++) {
                 imageMatrix[c][w-r-1] = imageMatrix[r][c];
             }
        }

public void rotate180(){ 
        rotate90(rotate90()); // my idea was to rotate again the already rotated matrix, but since rotate90 is void it doesn't work
}
```

Is there a way I can do this? With void functions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `rotate90()` has no parameter for that. Actually this is not the correct way.

The first way is to write it out.

```
rotate90();
rotate90();
```

Or use the `for-cycle`

```
for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    rotate90();
}
```

---

However here is a way to rotate it how many times you want with just a one method:

```
public void rotate90(int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (int r=0; r<w; r++) {
            for (int c=0; c<h; c++) {
                imageMatrix[c][w-r-1] = imageMatrix[r][c];
            }
        }
    }
```

And then the `rotate180()` method:

```
public void rotate180(){ 
    rotate90(2); // rotate by 90 two times
}
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work when I call rotate90 twice... Can you tell me more about the for-cycle way? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't rotate it 180, only 90 and I don't know why. Is it possible that it rotates a matrix 90 degrees and then again the same matrix, insted of rotating the new matrix? I think Ill just think of another way, without calling rotate90. Thanks again for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call the method twice. What you can't do is call `rotate90()` with the return value of `rotate90` which is what your proposed code is doing, since the method doesn't take a parameter or return a value.

Answer (score 2):

Your `rotate90()` is working directly on a global variable, so your `rotate180()` would too.

```
public void rotate180(){ 
    rotate90();
    rotate90();
}
```

However, I would suggest you to use some params and return values, only use global variables if strictly necesary. Also, I am not sure if your algorithm is correct, I would do it like this.

```
public static int[][] rotate90(int[][] matrix){
    int [][] newMatrix = new int[matrix[0].length][matrix.lenght];

    for (int r = 0; r < w; r++) {
         for (int c = 0; c < h; c++) {
             newMatrix[c][w-r-1] = matrix[r][c];
         }
    }
    return newMatrix;
}

public static int[][] rotate180(){ 
    return rotate90(rotate90()); 
}
```

There is no need to set them as `static` but since they don't need an object to work, you can move them to a `Utils` class or something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call it only once, you can pass it as a parameter

```
public void rotate90nTimes(int n){
    for (int times = 0; times < n; times++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < w; r++) {
             for (int c = 0; c < h; c++) {
                 imageMatrix[c][w-r-1] = imageMatrix[r][c];
             }
        }
    }
}
```

p.s.:
If you do want to use it as rotate90(rotate90) you need to return the matrix and not making the funcion as void.